# Zappa Init -- Flask UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 301: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, package

I am trying my hand at serverless deployment of an API... and getting annoyingly stuck at the setup stage.

I'm trying to run `zappa init` from `cmd`, but I am getting a weird error.

The command actually worked the first time I ran it (I cancelled at the last step, realizing I wanted to setup my S3 bucket first).

When I tried it again, after installing and configuring awscli, then installing flask to my virtual environment, I got the following error:

```
Your Zappa deployments will need to be uploaded to a private S3 bucket.
If you don't have a bucket yet, we'll create one for you too.
What do you want call your bucket? (default 'zappa-hohr3kxh7'):

It looks like this is a Flask application.
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\joshu\documents\code\machine-learning\boston-housing-price\app\env\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 2610, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "c:\users\joshu\documents\code\machine-learning\boston-housing-price\app\env\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 476, in handle
    self.init()
  File "c:\users\joshu\documents\code\machine-learning\boston-housing-price\app\env\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 1604, in init
    matches = detect_flask_apps()
  File "c:\users\joshu\documents\code\machine-learning\boston-housing-price\app\env\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\utilities.py", line 143, in detect_flask_apps
    lines = f.readlines()
  File "c:\users\joshu\documents\code\machine-learning\boston-housing-price\app\env\venv\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 301: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.6 Anaconda distribution.

Most of my code lies in an api.py file, other than that there is an index.html file. Here's the api.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import boto3
import numpy as np
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

BUCKET_NAME = 'ml-boston-housing'
MODEL_FNAME = 'model.pkl'

S3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')

# memoized annotation, caches model file after it's pulled
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}

    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]

    return helper


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def make_prediction():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        app.logger.info("{} request received from: {}".format(
            request.method, request.remote_addr))

        mdl = load_model(MODEL_FNAME)
        input_data = np.zeros((1, 13))

        if request.json or 'data' in request.json:
            for i, k in enumerate(request.get_json()):
                input_data[0, i] = request.form.get(k, 0)
            result = np.squeeze(mdl.predict(input_data))
            return jsonify({'result': result})
        else:           
            for i, k in enumerate(request.form.keys()):
                input_data[0, i] = request.form.get(k, 0)
            result = np.squeeze(mdl.predict(input_data))
            return render_template('index.html', label=result)



@memoize
def load_model(key):
    response = S3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=key)
    modelstr = response['Body'].read()
    model = pickle.load(modelstr)

    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to parse something that isn't CP1252 as if it were CP1252. And that something is probably either a Python source file or a Flask config file. How are you editing and saving those files? (If you're using Notepad—or, worse, Word—it's very easy to accidentally create a file that's UTF-16, or even not a textfile) Do any of them have any non-ASCII characters in them? If you're intentionally using non-ASCII characters and saving in UTF-8 or some other charset that isn't your system default, have you included a coding declaration?

Comment: I did just start using Visual Studio Code (as of 30 minutes before the bug... came with the new Anaconda download). I haven't included a coding declaration.. is this something I do at the module level, or do I need to configure the IDE? Or system settings?

Comment: VSCode is perfectly fine. But if you're using, say, UTF-8, and putting non-ASCII characters in your source files… see [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for full details, or just add `# coding: utf-8` to the top of your file (right after the `#!` line if you have one, or as the first line in the file if you don't). This goes in each `.py` file (or at least each `.py` file that has any non-ASCII characters in it).

Answer (score 1):

Kind of figured it out, when `Zappa init` runs, it calls `def detect_flask_apps()` function in the **utilities.py** file. This function reads each python file in the project directory, including the libraries in the virtual environment folder.

There is a library called functools.py that must have different character encodings than what is the default, because

```
with open(full, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

fails when reading `~/env/venv/Lib/functools.py`.

The fix is to specify the encoding:

```
with open(full, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

in `zappa/utilities.py -- line 148`